# Python Bottle: Router unable to match wildcard filter in the middle of a URL

Tags: python, bottle

I'm trying to use the :path wildcard filter (as described [here](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/routing.html#wildcard-filters)) to match part of my URL, which includes a forward slash character. For example, if I have the URL:

```
/resources/adfs89s7/container/asdf%2Fasdf/items
```

(where %2F is the forward slash), I want to match it to the route:

```
/resources/<resource_id>/container/<container_name:path>/items
```

However, this is currently returning a Not Found error. I have similar URLs where the wildcard filter is at the end of the URL, e.g.

```
/resources/<resource_id>/container/<container_name:path>
```

and that seems to work fine. Does anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: If the container name is escaped, why are you using `path`?  There's no need.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it looks like your container names are escaped (as they should be).  In that case, you don't need the `path` type specifier in the Bottle route.  I.e., you want this:

```
/resources/<resource_id>/container/<container_name>/items
```

Also keep in mind that the above route will *not* match paths with a trailing slash, so if this is intended to be a RESTful browsing API, then you may want to make the route:

```
/resources/<resource_id>/container/<container_name>/items/
```